# "new" item replaced by "cmd" in context menu in explorer.exe (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

So, for an unknown reason, the context menu in explorer.exe has no "new" item. Instead a "cmd" item appeared; as in the screenshot below (in French)

[image: See screenshot here (in French)]

When clicking on "cmd", a pop-up error window states :

> No program is associated to this file to execute this action. Install a program or create an association in the control panel.

and nothing else happens.

The "new folder" button on the explorer toolbar doesn't work either, as nothing happens when I click on it.

Here's what I tried :

- creating a new folder on the command-line with `mkdir` and this works, so the problem does not come from permission issues.
- running a system file check with `sfc /scannow` did not detect any error.

Any pointers on what I should look at next ?

Comment: I need a little more diagnostics information before I can answer you. Please open `regedit`, navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory`, export this key and share the resulting file with us. (Using Google Drive, OneDrive, pastebin.com, etc.)

Comment: Here is all registry keys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory` :
https://framabin.org/?2a8c3b6bdfc22ec6#u57oZowngodvW05YiuxY2elhxjC2KOg3G1GGI4OUPTY=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining the Registry profile, it appears several key Registry entries are missing. So, do the following:

1. Make a System Restore check point or run a backup. (We are modifying Registry; we don't want to accidentally break anything.
2. Open Notepad, paste the following script in it, and save the result as `"Directory entry.reg"` (**include** the quotation marks) while making sure the Encoding drop-down box in the Save dialog box says "Unicode".

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd]
   @="@shell32.dll,-8506"
   "Extended"=""
   "NoWorkingDirectory"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\command]
   @="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
   @="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"
   ```
3. Import the script into your Registry by double-clicking on it.

Now, in the above script, I only included code necessary to solve the problem in you question... But when I was comparing your copy of Directory key with my own (Windows 10 Enterprise 1607) I found other sub-entries missing. (Could there be problems in your Windows that you haven't noticed yet?) So, here is a fully mended "Directory" entry.

Use it wisely.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory]
@="File Folder"
"AlwaysShowExt"=""
"EditFlags"=hex:d2,01,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,77,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,2e,00,73,00,74,00,6f,\
  00,72,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,\
  31,00,35,00,32,00,00,00
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.DateCreated;System.FileCount;System.TotalFileSize"
"InfoTip"="prop:System.Comment;System.DateCreated"
"NoRecentDocs"=""
"PreviewDetails"="prop:System.DateModified;*System.SharedWith;*System.OfflineAvailability;*System.OfflineStatus"
"PreviewTitle"="prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemTypeText"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ FileSyncEx]
@="{CB3D0F55-BC2C-4C1A-85ED-23ED75B5106B}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
@="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Sharing]
@="{f81e9010-6ea4-11ce-a7ff-00aa003ca9f6}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\WorkFolders]
@="{E61BF828-5E63-4287-BEF1-60B1A4FDE0E3}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell]
@="none"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AddToPlaylistVLC]
@="Ajouter à la liste de lecture de VLC"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AddToPlaylistVLC\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:006698a6
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\find]
"LegacyDisable"=""
"SuppressionPolicy"=dword:00000080

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\find\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{a015411a-f97d-4ef3-8425-8a38d022aebc}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PlayWithVLC]
@="Lire avec VLC"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PlayWithVLC\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" --started-from-file --no-playlist-enqueue \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:006698a6

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ FileSyncEx]
@="{CB3D0F55-BC2C-4C1A-85ED-23ED75B5106B}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\EncryptionMenu]
@="{A470F8CF-A1E8-4f65-8335-227475AA5C46}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Offline Files]
@="{474C98EE-CF3D-41f5-80E3-4AAB0AB04301}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\EPP]
@="{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Sharing]
@="{f81e9010-6ea4-11ce-a7ff-00aa003ca9f6}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\WorkFolders]
@="{E61BF828-5E63-4287-BEF1-60B1A4FDE0E3}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\CopyHookHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\CopyHookHandlers\FileSystem]
@="{217FC9C0-3AEA-1069-A2DB-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\CopyHookHandlers\Sharing]
@="{40dd6e20-7c17-11ce-a804-00aa003ca9f6}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers\7-Zip]
@="{23170F69-40C1-278A-1000-000100020000}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers\Eraser]
@="{BC9B776A-90D7-4476-A791-79D835F30650}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Offline Files]
@="{7EFA68C6-086B-43e1-A2D2-55A113531240}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Sharing]
@="{f81e9010-6ea4-11ce-a7ff-00aa003ca9f6}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{1f2e5c40-9550-11ce-99d2-00aa006e086c}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{4a7ded0a-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{ECCDF543-45CC-11CE-B9BF-0080C87CDBA6}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{ef43ecfe-2ab9-4632-bf21-58909dd177f0}]
```

Comment: Why are the quotes necessary in the file name ?

Comment: @Louen If you type `Directory entry.reg`, Notepad will save a `Directory entry.reg.txt` for you. If you type `"Directory entry.reg"` with (quotation marks), Notepad will not add the `.txt` extension.